# What is the realistic depth in chess we can set in graphical user interface when we have hardware with 16 core processor with 32 threads?

Tags: computer-chess

I want know the depth we can set in 16 core processor and 32 threads time can be maximum set  to 15 seconds. Please share your thoughts and ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to search based on a time limit, you should be using iterative deepening search. That is: search to depth 1, then 2, then 3, etc. After you search to each depth level, check if you've exceeded the time limit (or are close to exceeding it).

This may seem inefficient but if you use a transposition table it actually gives the engine a significant boost since it can look at the best moves first on each iteration.